# check if tree is a subtree of another tree

Tags: haskell

I am trying to check out if tree is a subtree of another tree. Here is my data for Tree:

```
data Tree a = Empty | Node a (Tree a)(Tree a) deriving Show

tree1 :: Tree Int
tree1 = Node 1
        (Node 2
          (Node 4 Empty Empty)
          (Node 5 Empty
              (Node 8 Empty Empty))
        )
        (Node 3
          (Node 6 Empty
           (Node 9 Empty Empty))
           (Node 7 Empty Empty)
          )

tree2 :: Tree Int
tree2 = Node 2
        (Node 4 Empty Empty)
        (Node 5 Empty
            (Node 8 Empty Empty))
```

And finally def of unfulfilled function:

```
isSubTree :: Eq a => Tree a -> Tree a -> Bool
isSubTree _ Empty = False
isSubTree Empty _ = False
isSubTree (Node a l r) (Node b ll rr) | 
                                      | otherwise = False
```

I need a hint how to fulfill first guardian - should i use `elem` or any other basic function? If I would want to find any specific element in tree I would use code below, so should I somehow modify that code?

```
treeMember x (Node a l r) |x `elem` [a]  = True
                          |otherwise = treeMember x l || treeMember x r
```

Comment: You check if the threes are equal, if not if the left/right subchild is equal, and then recursively move down in the tree.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A tree *t<sub>1</sub>* is a (non-strict) subtree of a tree *t<sub>2</sub>* given the two trees are equal, or *t<sub>1</sub>* is a subtree of one of the (direct) children of *t<sub>2</sub>*.

We can let Haskell implement an instance for the [**`Eq`** typeclass](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Eq) with:

```
data Tree a = Empty | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a) deriving (Eq, Show)
```

So now we can implement a check with:

```
isSubtree :: Eq a => Tree a -> Tree a -> Bool
isSubtree t1 t2 | t1 == t2 = True
isSubtree t1 (Node _ c1 c2) = …
isSubtree _ _ = False
```

where you still need to fill in the `…` part. I leave this as an exercise.